# How to add $args to any running wp_query from function.php?

Tags: wp-query

Is it possible to add WP_Query arguments from functions.php to any of wp_query running on current page? For example, I want to add $args['order'] to current running wp_query on any pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [a `pre_get_posts` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) to modify the relevant query variables, with [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to target specific pages/queries (and probably return from the callback early on `is_admin()` so you do not affect dashboard queries).